# Change Password using md5 in PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, md5

When I tried to *update/change* the password it says that **my current password is wrong**,

I use md5 to encrypt the password but I don't know how to update the encrypted password using jQuery and Ajax.

This is the jQuery code that I'm using:

```
jQuery("#change_password").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var password = jQuery('#password').val();
            var current_password = jQuery('#current_password').val();
            var new_password = jQuery('#new_password').val();
            var retype_password = jQuery('#retype_password').val();
            if (password != current_password) {
                $.jGrowl("Password does not match with your current password  ", {
                    header: 'Change Password Failed'
                });
            } else if (new_password != retype_password) {
                $.jGrowl("Password does not match with your new password  ", {
                    header: 'Change Password Failed'
                });
            } else if ((password == current_password) && (new_password == retype_password)) {
                var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_password_mahasiswa.php",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (html) {

                        $.jGrowl("Your password is successfully change", {
                            header: 'Change Password Success'
                        });
                        var delay = 2000;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location = 'dashboard_mahasiswa.php'
                        }, delay);
                    }
                });
```

php code for updating the password:

```
<?php
  include('dbcon.php');
  include('session.php');
  $new_password  = $_POST['new_password'];
  $new_password  = md5($new_password)
  mysql_query("update mahasiswa set password = '$new_password' where mahasiswa_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You should post the password to the back end, where you handle all password verification and hashing.

Comment: do not use the `mysql_`-functions. they've been deprecated for years, and removed in php7. use mysql or pdo, and use parameterised statements - right now, your code is criminally vulnerable against **SQL injection attacks!** which means that sooner or later, your service _will_ leak sensitive data to hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following functions when you do hashing against your passwords:

```
password_hash()
password_verify()
password_needs_rehash()
password_get_info()
```

These are pretty handy if you want to do it the standard way. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/) is an article about it.

As per the updating of your new password, it is as same as any standard update query.

> UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2,... WHERE
>   some_column=some_value

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_update.asp) is more info.

Comment: Using `password_*` functions will of course mean that *all* passwords has to be stored with these functions, and verifying happens a bit differently than checking against a `md5()` hash. So OP should ditch the `md5()` "crypting", but has to alter his register and login modules as well to using `password_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `mysqli_query()` with prepared statements. To avoid SQL injection you have to use prepared statements.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update mahasiswa set password = ? where mahasiswa_id = ?");
$new_password = password_hash($_POST['new_password']);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $new_password, $session_id);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows === 0) exit('No rows updated');
$stmt->close();
```

A simple example which uses `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query()` .

```
 //$con must contain your database connection
 //eg:  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
 $new_password = password_hash($_POST['new_password']);
 $my_query = 'update mahasiswa set password = '.$new_password.' where mahasiswa_id = '.$session_id;
 if(mysqli_query($con,$my_query)){
     //database updated succesfully
 } else {
     //failure
 }
```

If you are working with `mysql_query()` then

```
 // if your db connection is valid then
 if(mysql_query($my_query)){
     //database updated succesfully
 } else {
     //failure
 }
```

Comment: Using `mysqli_` without prepared statement is not much better than using `mysql_`. You also have to update the connection if switching API (which one should, just use prepared statements). Also the already stored passwords needs to be update, the login/register module(s) also have to be updated if you're switching to `password_*` (which you should!). It's not neccesarily a simple replace.

Comment: i am currently working on the mysqli, I only want to use the md5 first for starter but even for that i cant change the password using the jQuery

Comment: Make sure these variables (password, current_password, new_password, retype_password ) contain exact value . Dont use md5 because which will break your system later. Make a seccur system.